# Is there a way to copy multiple rows based on a if condition formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to copy data from sheet 1 & 2 to sheet 3 if the condition matches.

i have tired following formulae

```
=IF('Sheet 1'!B$2='Sheet 2'!C2,'Sheet 2'!A2,"")
```

It only works for single cell in this case **'Sheet 2'!A2**. how can i use this condition to copy multiple values using my if condition & make it dynamic.

or power query is the only way to do it.

Comment: Not tested but maybe with FILTER function (only Excel365)

Comment: Have you tried the vlookup?

Comment: @RicardoEguia Vlookup is not working to get output of multiple values

Comment: just remove the "$" symbol in the formula and drag it downwards.